# Inherit parent width if child is smaller - child is positioned absolute

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter Bootstraps grid for my project.
I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span4 item">
        <div class="inner">Some text</div>
    </div>

    <div class="span4 item">
        <div class="inner">Some text</div>
    </div>

    <div class="span4 item">
        <div class="inner">Some text</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the following CSS:

```
.item {
    position: relative;
}

.item .inner {
    background: #fff;
}

.item:hover .inner,
.item .inner:hover { // I did them both because on mobile it catches only the first
    position: absolute;
}
```

The result is when i hover the ".item .inner", the length of the element is the same as ".item".
Inside of ".inner" i may have images with unknown width and i wish that those images stretch to their real width on mouse hover
but because ".item .inner" is limited to the width of ".item" (which maybe anything, depends on users screen) ".item .inner" wont stretch.

I thought maybe to remove "position: relative" from ".item" and this allowed ".item .inner:hover" to expand as much as necessary but if the content is shorter than ".item"'s width, it will shrink - This is a feature i don't want to happen

how is it possible to make it happen?

---

Edit:

In first case you can see what i have now - when you hover a text, it loses its width - but if you hover an image, it stretches. http://jsfiddle.net/g5nP7/

In this case you can see that if you hover a text it doesn't loses it's width, but if you hover the image, it won't stretch. http://jsfiddle.net/dT7c5/4/

What I want is when you hover a text - it will stretch only if the content inside is longer then the width of the item on hover.
I don't want it to shrink if the content is shorter then the item

also as you can see in both examples, if you hover an image, it loses it's height and forces other items to go up.

Answer (score 0):

The only pure CSS solution that I can come up with is to use a combination of `max-width` with `min-width`, taking away the `max-width` when hovered. Bootstrap made it a little harder to work with, but in essence I removed `span4` CSS and used media queries to achieve a very similar effect

```
... Some other CSS ...
.item .inner {
    ...
    width:auto;
}
.item:hover .inner, .item .inner:hover {
    max-width:none;
}
.span4.item { width:auto; }
@media screen and (min-width:980px) {
    .item .inner {
        min-width:265px;
        max-width:265px;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width:980px) and (min-width:770px) {
    .item .inner {
        min-width:200px;
        max-width:200px;
    }
}
```

[**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/g5nP7/2/). It is not 100% perfect because it uses media query break points instead of the kind of grid system bootstrap uses (I tried using percent widths to mimic the original functionality but it broke it), but with media queries it's hard to tell the difference. The only thing is that you may want to add another media query for larger screens to make it fit the screen a little better

Comment: in my case the min-width should be the width of .item (it doesn't has static width)

Comment: So the width is artificially larger than the original and you want to prevent it from going to its original size in this case? A live example would be helpful

Comment: In first case you can see what i have now - when you hover a text, it loses its width - but if you hoven an image, it streches. http://jsfiddle.net/g5nP7/

In this case you can see that if you hover a text it doesn't loses it's width, but if you hover the image, it won't stretch. http://jsfiddle.net/dT7c5/4/

Comment: @VladKucherov I updated my answer, hopefully it suits your needs

Comment: Well, this doesn't solves the problem. i figured that this can't be solved using CSS. so i thought i should listen to hover events and assign min width to "inner" as the width of "item".

Comment: you see, i need the get this working without media queries because they are irrelevant for my situation. What I described here, is a part of something which will change the width on the fly... so basically this should be independent and automatic.